# ANgularJS use data from previous page

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to use data from previous page?

I have two pages: '/users' and '/users/:id'

'/users' template:

```
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
   <div ng=repeat="(k,v) from data">
      <span>{{v.name}}</span>
      <a ng-href="/users/{{k}}">View details</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

'/users/:id' page

```
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
   <span>{{ data[currentId].name}}</span>

   <div>{{additional_data}}</div>
</div>




//Controller userCtrl
    $scope.currentId = $stateParams.id || false;
    $scope.data = {};

    $http.get('/users').then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response;

        // returns
        // $scope.data[1] = {name: 'Alex'};
        // $scope.data[2] = {name: 'Masha'};
    }

    $scope.additional_data = 'Some data';
```

On clicking on 'View detail' button we are going to another page with other template. But controller is the same.

Is there a way to save data and not call request again? Just render old data on new page?

Answer (score 2):

```
myApp.factory('CacheData', function{
  var scopeData=null;
  var setdata=function(data){
   scopeData=data;
  },
  var getdata=function(){
   return scopeData;
  }
});

//Controller file

 var data=CacheData.GetData(Data);
 if(data==null){
  //Write your code for getting data
  CacheData.SetData(Data); //set data for next call
 }
```

Here I have created service to save data. you can use **SetData** method to save data and use **Getdata** method to get back saved data.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into services. A service is usually used to 'save' data when navigating to a different part of the website or when you refresh the page.

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) is a link to the angular documentation on services. Basicly you inject the service in your controller and from one page store data in the service, then on the next page get the data from the service and use it on that page.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to use [ui-router.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

You can then define a parent state that uses that controller and both child states will have access to the same instance of the controller.

Something like this:

This should be inside a config block

```
  $stateProvider
    .state( 'users', {
      abstract : true,
      controller : // yourController,
      template : '<div ui-view></div>'
    })
      .state( 'users.list', {
        templateUrl : // whatever,
        url : '/users',
      })
      .state( 'users.detail', {
        templateUrl : // whatever,
        url : 'users/:id'
      });
```

Comment: I use it like you said. And how to resolve my problem with it?

Comment: What I showed you is the way of define states with ui-router. Once you have that set, you will have the same instance of the controller for both states.